# Como cuento elementos de diferente tipo en un mismo array?

Tags: javascript

Quiero contar cuantos números y letras hay en un mismo array. Por ejemplo:

```
var elementos =["k",2,7,"u",20]
```

¿Cómo puedo hacer para obtener por consola la cantidad de letras y números del mismo array?
Gracias!

Comment: Hola, se puede hacer muy simple, pero antes agrega el código que has intentado por favor.

Comment: Recorres el array y compruebas si es un numero o un string xd?

Answer (score 1):

Para contar los números puedes usar `filter()`, luego la cantidad de letras será la diferencia entre el tamaño del array y la cantidad de números.

```js
var elementos = ["k",2,7,"u",20];

var num = elementos.filter(n => n==0 || Number(n)).length;

var cont = elementos.length;

var total={
  numeros : num,
  letras : cont - num
}

console.log(total);
```

El funcionamiento es el siguiente:

Con `filter()` obtienes los elementos de un *array* que encajen en las especificaciones dadas en la función.

Para obtener solo números se emplea `Number(n)` el cual verifica que **n** sea un número.

Luego existe un detalle, `Number()` no reconoce el 0 como numero, de modo que debe validarse también `n==0`.

Espero sea lo que buscas, saludos.

Comment: Hay que tener en cuenta que `Number()` intenta convertir a number lo que le pases, por lo que `Number("")` o `Number(" ")`   y otras... retornan un número. Y no es que `Number(0)` no reconozca el 0, es que es `false` en una comparación lógica del tipo `algo || Number(n)`.

Comment: @Emeeus entendido, gracias por la acotación.

Answer (score 1):

Otra posibilidad puede ser agrupar todos los `typeof` con `.reduce()`

```js
var elementos = ["k", 2, 7, 20, [1, 2, 3], true, "u"];

const res = elementos.reduce((p, c) => {
  p[typeof c] = (p[typeof c] || 0) + 1;
  return p;
}, {});

console.log(res);
```

Answer (score 1):

Una solución puede ser la siguiente:

- Utilizamos [`Array.reduce`](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/Objetos_globales/Array/reduce) para recorrer y controlar los valores del arreglo.
- Utilizamos [`value.constructor.name`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/constructor) para obtener **el nombre del tipo** del valor.

#### Ejemplo:

```js
let elementos = ["k", 2, {a: 1}, 20, [1], true, new Date(), function() {}, null, undefined];

const count = elementos.reduce((acc, val) => {
  let typeName = val === null ? 'null' : 
    val === undefined ? 'undefined' : val.constructor.name;

  acc[typeName] = acc[typeName] + 1 || 1;
  return acc;
}, {});

console.log(count);
```

Comment: A mi me parece bien, es lo mas escalable que se puede, aunque sobrepasa con creces lo que pide OP.